# .htaccess rewriterule folder and files rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have problem with my rewrite rule. I have new webpage in root/hrp. and if i open pages in that directory, then all is OK, but when i wanna surf those pages from root (without /hrp/) then is problem. I found some .htaccess rules and all working fine, but if i wanna execute some pdf,jpg,or php script directly, then come problem.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hrp/
RewriteRule (.*) /hrp/$1  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hrp/index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

if i put this bottom code on begining, i can open files directli, but pages don't work and vice versa

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.xml|\.rss|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the top instead:

```
RewriteRule \.(php|html?|png|jpe?g|gif|xml|rss|feed|pdf|raw)$ - [L,NC]
```

or you can try adding this condition to your hrp rule:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/hrp/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/hrp/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) /hrp/$1  [L]
```

Comment: same problem if i put on begining, or bottom, and if i put other code, problem is then i must change a lot files becouse includes in hrp is then not working....

Comment: better idea, how to exclude extensions from rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

I have find solution

## don't rewrite this files

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js|swf|wav|mp3|less|cur|pdf|jpeg|txt|ico|zip|gz) [NC]

## don't rewrite this folder - there i have php files, and dont rewrite this files

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(folder1|folder2|file1.php|file2.php|file3.php) [NC]

## all content is in "/hrp/" folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hrp/

RewriteRule (.*) /hrp/$1  [L]

## but url don't contains "/hrp/"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hrp/index.php

RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L]